# Excel formula to derive next available date basis uneven frequency

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Below is a table where Column A has given date, and Column C through I are days on which future dates can occur. 0 stand for cannot occur, 1 stand for can occur.

Basis the occurrence, I am trying to figure out a formula which can tell me what is the next available date.

For Ex: In case of Monday 8th Jun, Mon is 0, hence next available date is Tue 8th Jun

For Ex: In case of Sunday 13th Jun, Mon & Sun are 0, hence next available date is Tue 15th Jun.

While (**if**) formula can handle this, but the frequency nature is dynamic hence need a smarter approach.

Preferably a formula based approach.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following array formula in `B2`:
`=A2+IFERROR(SMALL(IF(($C$2:$I$2=1)*(COLUMN($C$2:$I$2)>=WEEKDAY(A2,2)+2),COLUMN($C$2:$I$2)),1)-WEEKDAY(A2,2)-2,SMALL(IF($C$2:$I$2=1,COLUMN($C$2:$I$2)),1)-WEEKDAY(A2,2)-2+7)`

Array-formula is entered with `ctrl+shift+enter`

[image]

`WEEKDAY(A2,2)` returns the number of the day in the week: `1` for Monday, `2` for Tuesday, etc. `SMALL(IF(($C$2:$I$2=1)*(COLUMN($C$2:$I$2)>=WEEKDAY(A2,2)+2),COLUMN($C$2:$I$2)),1)-WEEKDAY(A2,2)-2` This part makes an array of the current row and returns the smallest column number that meet the following conditions: 1) cell in the range (row) has value 1. 2) the column number of the cells resulting from condition 1 is equal to or greater than the calculated `WEEKDAY` +2 (weekday for Monday = 1+2 =3) so if column 3 contains value 1 it's a hit, else it will look for the first next column that does meet the conditions. As the desired result should return the date of the result we add the column of the result of this evaluation to the original date and extract the WEEKDAY -2 (minus, because we need to extract *more). The IFERROR is built to search in the next row if there is no value 1 in the column equal to or greater than weekday +2. In that case it would return the first column of the next row containing value 1.

Comment: really nice - it is a deceivingly hard problem to address

Comment: while the result is correct, can you explain what the formula is doing.

Comment: I desired to add it to the answer. Hope it's understandable.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 2019 or Excel 365, in B, you could put the formula:

```
=LET( gDate, A2,
      pattern, C2:I2,
       s, SEQUENCE( 7, 7, 0 ),
       k, MOD( s, 8 ) - ( INT(s/7) > MOD(s,7) ),
       gDate + MIN( IF( pattern > 0, INDEX( k, WEEKDAY( gDate,3 )+1, ) ) ) )
```

I keep thinking that there has to be a simpler way than this, but none of my simpler approaches generate the results you are trying to achieve.

[image: screenshot]